# How to fix Traceback (most recent call last): number + 7 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

This is the code that I made:

```
number = input("What day number does your anime come out? ")
epi = input("How many episodes are there? ")

for epi in range(12):
  print(number)
  number + 7
```

the entire error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kevinforstner/anime release calc.py", line 6, in <module>
    number + 7
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: @NMme I really doubt OP will want to concatenate a string here. It's much more likely they want `number` to be a number and not a string and add 7 to it. Hard to say without OP clarifying this though.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek good point, I think it is most likely what OP wants

Answer (score 3):

In python, when you take input, it will be considered a string by default, so you'll need to parse the input as an integer, like this:

```
number = int(input("What day number does your anime come out? "))
```

Only then, `number + 7` will be an addition of two integers, else it is considered that you're trying to append the integer 7 to the string `number`, and a TypeError will be raised.